# How do i filter using a list created from filtered dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

A question regarding filtering using a list of values. I want to do the following:

1. filter a dataframe based on certain criteria
2. create a list of (one column, containing ID's) of this dataframe
3. next i want to exclude this list from another dataframe.

all individual steps are working using the following code:

*df3 = df2.loc[df2['value']  < parameter]*             **(1)**

*my_list = df3['ID'].tolist()*                         **(2)**

*final_df = df[~df['column'].isin(my_list)]*           **(3)**

yet somehow filtering the frame using the first step results in the final step NOT working (so not filtering anything). When i remove the first step it again works like a charm. Does anybody know what i am doing wrong?

kind regards,

Alex

Comment: Does changing `my_list = df3['ID'].tolist()` to `my_list = df3['ID'].values.tolist()` make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

can not confirm without having a look at an example dataframe. But You can try the same using joins and see if it produce the same answer. Other wise there might be a bug some where in your code.

```py
PARAMETER = 30
df3 = df2[df["value"] < PARAMETER]
merged_df = df.merge(df3[["ID"]], on="ID", how="left", indicator=True)
final_df = merged_df[merged_df["_merge"] == "left_only"]
final_df = final_df.drop("_merge", axis=1)
```

I have not tested the code, it might need modification, it is just a concept which you can try out. Here I have used a join with an indicator which will add a new column in the merged dataframe as an indicator if the row comes from left table or right table and then I kept only the data comes from left table. This approach can also be faster than list approach, but can not confirm

Comment: Hi DataPsycho, Thanks for the quick reply, didnt completely got your code working. But solved the issue by forcing type 'integer' between step 1 and 2!

Answer (score 0):

Changed datatype to 'integer' between step 1 and 2.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).